# How to make stochastic gradient descent not ultimately kill all weights

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent, backpropagation

Stochastic gradient descent as I understand it, is implemented as follows:

Activate the network, read output neurons, compare to desired output, calculate derivatives on weights, update weights, activate with new example.

However, let's say I have the following dataset:

```
[
  { input: [0, 0], output: [0] },
  { input: [0, 1], output: [0] },
  { input: [1, 0], output: [0] },
  { input: [1, 1], output: [1] },
]
```

So if I update the weights to decrease the output of the output neuron in 3 out of 4 cases, ultimately, over time I will set my weights to produce an output of 0 or close thereof.

Which mechanism insures that I will get an output of 1 if both input neurons are activated with 1?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a method to do that. But when you have a dataset which you need to perform a classification task on, it is a good practice to make sure you have an almost uniform distribution of classes in the dataset.

Comment: Right, but even so.. If you got let's say 5 classes, you will influence the weights towards 0 in 4 out of 5 examples

Comment: I didn't mean to increase the number of classes. I meant to make the distribution of classes uniform, i.e., all classes have an approximately equal number of samples. I don't think there is any other way to do it.

Comment: Well ok, good, this actually works now sometimes a little bit! Thank you for that (no sarcasm)

However, it only does if I only have 2 classes so that I influence every neuron towards 1 and 0 half the time.

But if I have 3 classes, my output would be [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0] so I influence the weights of each neuron towards 0 twice as often as towards 1 and the problem increases with each additional class, even if I have an even distribution of samples